# function not being recognized

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

```
hideOverlay: function () {
    if (this.interceptHide && this.interceptHide()) {
        return false;
    }
    window.marvel._dialogShowing = false;
    $(document).off('keyup', this.handleKeyup);
    $(window).off('scroll.scrolldisabler');
    this.$el.addClass('hide');
    if (this.onHide) {
        this.onHide();
    }
},

handleKeyup: function (evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode === domKeys.DOM_VK_ESCAPE &&                !this._ignoreCloseActions) {
        this.hideOverlay();
    }
}
```

I have the functions above in a Backbone view. When handleKeyup is called it should call hideOverlay; however, I get a message saying that hideOverlay function is undefined. Even though its clearly defined as you see above. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow J K :) Could you show the entire View code? That would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guess that you're binding your `handleKeyup` with something like this:

```
$(document).on('keyup', this.handleKeyup);
```

and from the [fine manual](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-handler):

> **.on()**
>   [...]
>   When jQuery calls a handler, the `this` keyword is a reference to the element where the event is being delivered; [...]

So `this` isn't the view when `handleKeyup` is called, it will be some DOM element that won't have a `hideOverlay` method.

A quick an easy solution would be to bind the `handleKeyup` method in your view's `initialize`:

```
initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'handleKeyup');
    // Whatever else you're already doing...
}
```

Then `this` will be the view no matter how `handleKeyup` is called.